# Number of coprimes of $n$ divisible by 3

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I'm looking for a formula for $C(n)$ := the number of coprimes of $n$ in the range $[1, n]$ divisible by 3, where $n$ is any positive integer. The formula should be quick to compute, preferably at similar speed as computing $\varphi(n)$, the [totient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of $n$, so it can use the factorization of numbers of similar size as $n$.

I know that if $n$ is divisible by 3, then $C(n)=0$.

I know that if $n$ is not divisible by 3, then $\varphi(n)-C(n)$ equals to the 
number of coprimes of $n$ in the range $[1, n]$ not divisible by 3, which equals to the number of coprimes of $3n$ in the range $[1, n]$. For this quantity there is a formula at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/983287/5758: $\varphi(3n) / 3$, but it's proven true only if $\varphi(3n)/3$ is an integer. I need a general formula which works for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: What about simply $floor(\phi (3n)/3)$ ?

Comment: @Peter: $\mathrm{floor}(\varphi(3n)/3)$ is incorrect for many numbers smaller 100. $\mathrm{ceil}(\varphi(3n)/3)$ is also incorrect for many numbers smaller 100. Both are incorrect for $n=110$ and many other numbers.

Comment: For $n=1870$, I get $C(n)=216$, $floor(\phi(1870)/3)=213$ , so the difference is already greater than $1$, even if we take ceil.

Comment: So, $floor(\phi(n)/3)$ does, alas, also not work.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, as I wrote in my previous comment, neither $\mathrm{floor}(\varphi(3n)/3)$ nor $\mathrm{ceil}(\varphi(3n)/3)$ work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an algorithm to compute $C(n)$ which is a bit slower than I wanted: it first factorizes $n$ and then it uses the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) on $c$ sets, where $c$ is the number of prime factors of $n$. So the time needed is the factorization time of $n$ plus $O(c\cdot 2^c)$ for computing all the terms in the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Let $A_i$ := the set of integers in $[1,n]$ divisible by 3 and divisible by $p_i$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime factor of $n$. In this case $C(n) = n - |\cup A_i|$.

It's easy to compute the size of the intersections of any number of sets in $A_i$, for example if $p_1=3$, $p_2=7$, $p_3=11$, then $|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|=\lfloor n / 3 / 7 / 11\rfloor$. Once we have the sizes of all $2^c$ set intersections, we can use the inclusion-exclusion principle to sum them with alternating signs to get $|\cup A_i|$. And from that we get $C(n)$.

Here is a Python function which computes $C(n)$:

```
def C(n):
  """Returns the count of numbers in xrange(3, 1 + n, 3) coprime to n."""
  ps = []
  for p in factorize(n):
    if not ps or ps[-1] != p:  # Skip duplicate primes.
      ps.append(p)
  c = len(ps)
  result = 0
  for ii in xrange(1 << c):  
    sign = 1  
    product = 3
    for j in xrange(c):
      if ii & (1 << j):
        sign = -sign
        if ps[j] != 3:
          product *= ps[j]
    result += sign * (n // product)
  return result
```